Return a generic type from various lists
I'm not sure if this is possible or not but I have a couple of dictionaries of different value types.
public Dictionary<int, Type1> type1;
public Dictionary<int, Type2> type2;

And I want to be able to use generics to grab an object of a specific type.
public T Get<T>(int ID)
{
    // somehow find the correct dictionary and return its value
}

I could use a switch statement but is there a smarter way?

Use polymorphism instead of a conditional switch. Look into simple patterns like strategy or factory.

Smarter? What about not using a generic method but individual explicit methods for explicit types? You must name the concrete T when calling Get so i don't see it as an improvment having made this generic if there isn't anything that needs that generic approach.

You can try using reflection, if those fields are class fields in the same class as the Get method.
Example implementation:
public class TestArea
{
    public Dictionary<int, Type1> type1 = new Dictionary<int, Type1> { { 1, new Type1() } };
    public Dictionary<int, Type2> type2 = new Dictionary<int, Type2> { { 1, new Type2() } };
    
    public T Get<T>(int ID)
    {
        var dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<int, T>);

        var dictionaryProperty = GetType()
            .GetFields()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldType == dictionaryType);

        if (dictionaryProperty is null) throw new Exception("No dictionary found!");

        var dictionary = (Dictionary<int, T>)dictionaryProperty.GetValue(this);

        return dictionary[ID];
    }
}

